# vue.js 3 composable and reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity, composable

Given the following composable 'useNumbers.js' in vue.js 3,
I'd like to have 'numbers' in the components reactive. But adding new values to numbers in 1 component is not reflected in the 2nd component.

useNumbers.js:

```
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default function() {
    const numbers = ref([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

    const addNumber = num => {
        numbers.value.push(num);
    }

    const filterNumber = minNum => {
        return numbers.value.filter(curNum => curNum >= minNum);
    }

    return { numbers, addNumber, filterNumber }
}
```

Component A:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Child component</h1>
        <p>{{ numbers  }}</p>
        <button @click="addNumber(45)">Add 45</button>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <GrandChild />
    </div>
</template>


<script setup>

import useNumbers from '../composables/useNumbers';
import GrandChild from './GrandChild.vue';

const { numbers, addNumber } = useNumbers()

</script>
```

Component B:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>GreatGrandChild component</h1>
        <p>{{  numbers }}</p>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

import useNumbers from '../composables/useNumbers';

const { numbers } = useNumbers();

</script>
```

Whenever I click the button in Component A (which pushes 45 to the array, the change is not reflected in component B. I know, that deconstruction like

```
const { numbers, addNumber } = useNumbers()
```

destroys reactivity. I've played around using toRef and toRefs, but got no solution so far.

Comment: A composable and global state are different things. Calling composable function is the same as pasting function body inside a component, this is how JS works. if you expect a state to be global then https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

Comment: You are probably looking for stores. Check out pinia for storing values across components: https://pinia.vuejs.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the same state across multiple `useNumbers` instances, you can lift the state outside of the function and then it will only be created once.

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';

const numbers = ref([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

export default function() { 
  ...
  return { numbers }
}
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 1):

The main cause of your problem is that every time you call the useNumbers function, you create a new instance of the numbers object. Therefore, each component has its own copy of numbers which is not shared between components.

Use the store!